# Guardar cambios al recargar la pagina Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Estoy realizando un ejercicio practico. ya tengo casi todo listo solo tengo un problema que no he podido resolver, he buscado por varios medios pero no llego a entender como realizarlo. pues en la aplicación hay varias Cajas que se representan como horarios, los cuales al dar clic en uno de ellos cambia de color y agrega un icono, yo quiero que cuando recargue la pagina quede guardado los cambios. Yo se que con el LocalStorage puede realizarlo pero como dije anteriormente no se como hacerlo, llevo 3 días buscando la manera de como agregarlo e inclusive por mi cuenta intente varios métodos con lo que leí en la documentación pero no me queda claro o no me funciona. dejo el código  .js. si se dan cuenta en una parte del código intenté aplicar el localStorage pero no me funciona, espero que me puedan ayudar. Por favor

```js
const horario = document.getElementById("horarios");
let hora = 7;

//Mostrar el Horario Permitido del servicio
for (let i = 6; i < 15; i++) {
    hora++;
    horario.innerHTML += `
<div class="card my-2 bar d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="card-body fs-1 ">
            ${hora + ':00'}
         <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
          
            </span> 
        </div>      
    </div>           
       <div class="card bar my-2 ${'n' + hora} d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="card-body fs-1 ">
            ${hora + ':30'}
                  <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
          
            </span> 
        </div> 
    </div>
   `;
}
const hidden = document.querySelector('.n16');
hidden.className = 'd-none';
const recurse = document.getElementById('recurse');
const m = document.getElementById('m');
    const card = document.getElementsByClassName('card-body');
let motos = 8;

(()=>{
    recurse.innerHTML = `<span class="material-icons fs-1 ">
                        two_wheeler
                        </span><h3>${motos}</h3>`
    for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        card[i].addEventListener('click',select);
    }

})();

ls = localStorage;
arr = [];

const remover = (e) =>{

    e.path[0].classList.remove('sucess-color');
    e.path[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = '';
    motos++;
   arr.pop();
    ls.setItem('agg',JSON.stringify(arr))


}
const agregar = (e) =>{
    e.path[0].classList.add('sucess-color');
    e.path[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = 'two_wheeler';
    motos--;
    arr.push(e.path[0].childNodes[1].innerText);
    ls.setItem('agg',JSON.stringify(arr))


}

function select (e){
    if (e.target.classList.contains('sucess-color')) {
        remover(e);
        if (motos >= 1) {
            m.classList.replace('bg-danger', 'bg-white')
            mensaje.innerHTML=""
        }
    } else {
        if (motos > 0) {
                agregar(e);
            if (motos == 0) {
                m.classList.replace('bg-white', 'bg-danger');
                mensaje.innerHTML =`  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alertdialog" >
Ya no hay disponible
            </div>`
            }
        }
    }
    recurse.innerHTML = `<span class="material-icons fs-1 "> two_wheeler  </span><h3>${motos}</h3>`;


    e.stopPropagation();

}


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark mb-xl-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-center" href="#">Servicio de Motos</a>
    </div>

</header>
<div class="container d-flex">

<div class="container text-center " id="horarios">
</div >

    <div class=" mt-5 text-center text-dark  w-100 h-75 ">
        <div class="container w-50 position-fixed  card border-dark bg-white " id="m">
            <h2>Recursos</h2>
            <div id="recurse">
            </div>
        <div id="mensaje">

        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>







<script src="js/js.js?5"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No encontré ninguna error en tu código con respecto al localstorage, tu problema es que tu variable arr no se almacena en el localstorage?

Comment: Sería interesante que nos proporciones un [mre]... ya que has puesto un snippet de JS, si no añades también el HTML relacionado es un poco imposible ver qué está pasando exactamente :/ Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para que entiendas mejor cómo funciona SO y cómo elaborar una pregunta correctamente

Comment: ya agregué el cod HTML

Comment: lo que pasa es que si me guarda los datos en el localstorage pero el problema es que al momento de refrescar la pagina, todos estos cambios se eliminan en la pagina pero se mantienen en el localstorage. guarde esos cambios en un array porque como son varias cajas entonces pensé que si guardandolo ahí pudiera guardar esos cambios en las cajas seleccionadas. pero realmente no se :/

Comment: disculpen si no me explico bien :/ pero si lo copian el codigo y lo ejecutan, verán maso menos lo que quiero.  uso bootstrap y materialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***CODIGO FINAL:***

```
const horario = document.getElementById("horarios");
let hora = 7;

//Mostrar el Horario Permitido del servicio
ls = localStorage;
let motoId = 0
let motosReservadas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('agg')) || [];

for (let i = 6; i < 15; i++) {
  hora++;
  horario.innerHTML += `
<div class="card my-2 bar d-flex flex-wrap" motoId=${motoId}>
        <div class="card-body fs-1 ${motosReservadas.includes(motoId) ? 'sucess-color':''}">
            ${hora + ':00'}
         <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
              ${motosReservadas.includes(motoId) ? 'two_wheeler':''}
            </span> 
        </div>      
        </div>   

        <div class="card bar my-2 ${'n' + hora} d-flex flex-wrap" motoId=${motoId + 1}>
         <div class="card-body fs-1 ${motosReservadas.includes(motoId+1) ? 'sucess-color':''}">
             ${hora + ':30'}
                   <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
                   ${motosReservadas.includes(motoId+1) ? 'two_wheeler':''}
             </span> 
         </div> 
     </div>
   `;
    motoId += 2
}

const hidden = document.querySelector('.n16');
hidden.className = 'd-none';
const recurse = document.getElementById('recurse');
const m = document.getElementById('m');
const card = document.getElementsByClassName('card-body');
let motos = 8 - motosReservadas.length;

(() => {
  recurse.innerHTML = `<span class="material-icons fs-1 ">
                        two_wheeler
                        </span><h3>${motos}</h3>`
  for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
    card[i].addEventListener('click', select);
  }

})();


const remover = (e) => {
  e.path[0].classList.remove('sucess-color');
  e.path[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = '';
  motos++;
  motosReservadas.pop();
  ls.setItem('agg', JSON.stringify(motosReservadas))


}
const agregar = (e) => {
  e.path[0].classList.add('sucess-color');
  e.path[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = 'two_wheeler';
  const motoId = e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("motoId")
  motosReservadas.push(Number(motoId))
  ls.setItem('agg', JSON.stringify(motosReservadas))
  motos--;
}

function select(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('sucess-color')) {
    remover(e);
    if (motos >= 1) {
      m.classList.replace('bg-danger', 'bg-white')
      mensaje.innerHTML = ""
    }
  } else {
    if (motos > 0) {
      agregar(e);
      if (motos == 0) {
        m.classList.replace('bg-white', 'bg-danger');
        mensaje.innerHTML = `  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alertdialog" >
Ya no hay disponible
            </div>`
      }
    }
  }
  recurse.innerHTML = `<span class="material-icons fs-1 "> two_wheeler  </span><h3>${motos}</h3>`;


  e.stopPropagation();

}
```

***EXPLICACION:***

Tu principal problema es que guardas la información pero no haces nada con ella.

Para solucionar esto puedes crear una variable que almacene lo que tienes en el localstorage para luego usar esta información, algo así:

```
let motosReservadas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('agg')) || [];
```

Bien, ahora que tenemos la información en nuestro script podemos utilizarla, pero antes necesitamos identificar cada moto con un id único, el id podríamos crearnos una variable que controle eso

```
let motoId = 0
```

y en el bucle usaremos ese id para identificar las motos que tengan un horario que terminen en :00 ej: 8:00 9:00 10:00 etc

```
//Mostrar el Horario Permitido del servicio
for (let i = 6; i < 15; i++) {
    hora++;
    horario.innerHTML += `
<div class="card my-2 bar d-flex flex-wrap" motoId=${motoId}>
        <div class="card-body fs-1 ">
            ${hora + ':00'}
         <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
          
            </span> 
        </div>      
    </div>           
       <div class="card bar my-2 ${'n' + hora} d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="card-body fs-1 ">
            ${hora + ':30'}
                  <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
          
            </span> 
        </div> 
    </div>
   `;
```

Bien ahora nos falta las que terminan en :30 ej: 8:30 9:30 etc pero para que no utilicen el mismo id de las que terminan en :00 le sumaremos 1 para que se distingan

Y luego al terminar el bucle le sumamos 2, para que cuando cambie el i (indice) del bucle no comience desde 0 sino desde 2

```
//Mostrar el Horario Permitido del servicio
for (let i = 6; i < 15; i++) {
    hora++;
    horario.innerHTML += `
<div class="card my-2 bar d-flex flex-wrap" motoId=${motoId}>
        <div class="card-body fs-1 ">
            ${hora + ':00'}
         <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
          
            </span> 
        </div>      
    </div>           
       <div class="card bar my-2 ${'n' + hora} d-flex flex-wrap" motoId=${motoId+1}>
        <div class="card-body fs-1 ">
            ${hora + ':30'}
                  <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
          
            </span> 
        </div> 
    </div>
   `;

motoId += 2
```

luego en la función de agregar cuando le damos click al horario hay que obtener el id de la moto, convertirlo a numero y finalmente agregarlo a nuestro array de motos reservadas (o horario reservado)

```
const agregar = (e) => {
  e.path[0].classList.add('sucess-color');
  e.path[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML = 'two_wheeler';
  const motoId = e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("motoId")
  motosReservadas.push(Number(motoId))
  ls.setItem('agg', JSON.stringify(motosReservadas))
  motos--;
}
```

Y ahora volviendo al bucle donde se generan las motos (o horarios) debemos fijarnos si pertenecen al array de motos reservadas y si pertenecen agregarle el icono `two_wheeler` y la clase `sucess-color`, para esto podemos utilizar el [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator) y el [metodo includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) de los arrays quedando algo asi:

```
for (let i = 6; i < 15; i++) {
  hora++;
  horario.innerHTML += `
<div class="card my-2 bar d-flex flex-wrap" motoId=${motoId}>
        <div class="card-body fs-1 ${motosReservadas.includes(motoId) ? 'sucess-color':''}">
            ${hora + ':00'}
         <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
              ${motosReservadas.includes(motoId) ? 'two_wheeler':''}
            </span> 
        </div>      
        </div>   

        <div class="card bar my-2 ${'n' + hora} d-flex flex-wrap" motoId=${motoId + 1}>
         <div class="card-body fs-1 ${motosReservadas.includes(motoId+1) ? 'sucess-color':''}">
             ${hora + ':30'}
                   <span class="material-icons fs-1 moto ">
                   ${motosReservadas.includes(motoId+1) ? 'two_wheeler':''}
             </span> 
         </div> 
     </div>
   `;
    motoId += 2
}
```

Y por ultimo no nos podemos olvidar de actualizar la cantidad de motos disponibles, esto lo podríamos lograr restándole a la cantidad **inicial** de motos (8) la cantidad de motos **ya ocupadas**

```
let motos = 8 - motosReservadas.length;
```

Comment: Bro, muchisimas gracias!. Eso era lo que no podia hacer y era el problema ps no usar los datos guardados pero no sabia como, pero muchas gracias. me  funciona perfecto! Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Me podrían ayudar. Quiero saber lo mismo. O casi.. pero sin usar localstorage ni cookies.
Quiero que se guarden los cambios aunque se recargue la página.
Ejemplo tengo un botón rojo. Que cambie azul. Y al recargar la página.se guarde..

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, 
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.